# Zend Framework on Raspberry Pi throws Zend_Config_Exception 'Section '' cannot be found in (...)'

Tags: zend-framework, raspberry-pi, fatal-error, bootstrapping

I was trying to get an existing ZEND project running on my Raspberry Pi, but unfortunately, it throws this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'Section '' cannot be found in /var/www/BY_test/application/configs/session.ini' in /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php:151 
Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/BY_test/application/Bootstrap.php(41): Zend_Config_Ini-&gt;__construct('/var/www/BY_tes...', false)
    #1 /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap-&gt;_initSession()
    #2 /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;_executeResource('session')
    #3 /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;_bootstrap(NULL)
    #4 /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;bootstrap(NULL)
    #5 /var/www/BY_test/public/index.php(44): Zend_Application-&gt;bootstrap()
    #6 {main}
thrown in /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php on line 151
```

Since I'm new to Zend Framework, I'd really appreciate some help of someone more experienced.

I've already tried to find a solution myself, but the only post I found from someone with a similar problem was solved by deleting the getenv()-function for the APPLICATION_ENV in Bootstrap.php. Good for him, but that didn't do it for me.

It looks strange to me, that in the message the actual section is missing. I thought, this was an important clue, so I dabbled a little in some of the files mentioned in the error message, but like I said, I've only just begun working with Zend, so that was kind of pointless.

Also, I thought this was a matter of the operating system it's running on, since the project originally ran on a Windows server and I use Raspbian on the Pi. But I could (at least partially) rule this out.

Any ideas, what I could check next or what the problem might be?

FYI, the project's Zend Framework version is 1.12 and I use Apache/2.2.22 (Debian).
If you need further information on anything, just tell me. I just didn't want to swamp you with needless information 'cause I have no idea, what you need to know.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

PHP version on the Pi is 5.4.4-14+deb7u7 (the version on the original Windows server is 5.4.16)

Contents of session.ini:

```
;#####################################
; setup sessions
;#####################################

[production]
name = FLOID_BACKYARD
save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
use_only_cookies = true
remember_me_seconds = 864000

[development : production]
save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
use_only_cookies = true
remember_me_seconds = 864000
```

and the __initSession function of Bootstrap.php (line 41 reads '$config = ...'):

```
protected function _initSession()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/session.ini', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));
    Zend_Session::setOptions($config->toArray());
    Zend_Session::start();
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the contents of session.ini, and the part of Bootstrap.php that's generating this error (basically the function that's at line 41)? Also, since you implied this is a project that was working on another server, what version of PHP do you have on your Pi?

Comment: Okay, done. As I said, I heard someone solving the problem by deleting the getenv()-function and using the APPLICATION_ENV instead (as far as I know), but that didn't help.

Comment: Hmm, that all looks okay. My guess is that `APPLICATION_ENV` is not set - this would cause the error you're getting. Could you check you `public/index.php` file to see if there's anything relating to `APPLICATION_ENV`? Normally it will define the var, defaulting to 'production'

Comment: Do you mean this part right here?

`defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));`

But it's running perfectly well on the original server, and when I echo the `APPLICATION_ENV`, it is indeed set to 'production'.

Comment: what about if you echo `getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');`?

Comment: There's no output for `echo getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')`. Apparently, it returns 'false'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the quick fix for you problem would be to change this line:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/session.ini', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));
```

to:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/session.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
```

which is probably what it should be anyway. My guess is that on your other server, the environment variable was being set somewhere with `SetEnv`, but this isn't really necessary if you're running it in production mode.

Comment: Well, first of all, thanks for your efforts!
Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, because I then get another error reading:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /var/www/BY_test/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:469) (...)'`
It now also says, there are three Array to String conversions in library/Zend/Session/Exception.php, lines 58 and 71 :(

Comment: That's a separate error. Is that the full error message you posted or is there more info in the `(...)` bit? Just guessing looking at your session.ini config, but try changing `FLOID_BACKYARD` to a string rather than a constant (something like `'session'`), and also check that the server can write to the `data/session` folder in your app.

Comment: Oh, alright, I thought this error was the result of changing the getenv() bit, my bad. I had to cut out the majority of this error due to the character limitation. It goes on with some permission denials, so I guess, you are right on that one, too. Let me see, if I can fix it...

Comment: Okay, I think I sorted it out. It's definitely become an issue of access permissions now, but that's an other topic ;-)
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Set in .htaccess inside the /public

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.